# Break link with external document MS Word, Part 2

Tags: microsoft-word

This is a follow on question to the post "Break link with external document MS Word" but I have no idea how to ask a further question in that thread (the page only offers the ability to "answer" the question and now ask follow-up questions).

Thanks for all of the recommendations in that post, but I'm still experiencing this problem.  I have two constraints:
1. I need the charts to maintain their Excel features such as the ability to change the axis or color of a line (but I don't need, or want, the worksheet to be embedded in the Word document because its 10M in size).
2. I can't delete all of my charts (which was one of the suggestions above to fix the problem).

I never use "Paste Link" and yet the links back to Excel show up in Word every time I paste a new graph into my Word document, which then causes errors when I run a third-party program because I keep getting the error message that it can't find the link back to the chart (A LINK I DON'T NEED OR WANT...AGGG!!!).

About 20%-25% of the time, I can open a blank Excel file, create a dummy chart and then paste the chart into a blank Word document and the links don't appear.  But the other 80% of the time they do and so I have to go and break the links and then I get the "Null" and then errors when running the third party software.

So frustrating.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.